# Adding new Tables in an Open Source Script (Beginner Question)

Tags: php

I'm still a new php beginner, in fact I just started learning couple a days ago.

I love to learn and implement at the same time on real scripts because that's motivate me to continue learning.

Yesterday I put my hands on an open source script (File Uploading Script)

And the script is pretty simple, and I want to create categories in the script

Example: When someone would like to upload he can choose the categorie of the file so it can be added there. I should create the values of the categorie (either in MYSQL or from Control panel)

What I want: I want you guys to tell me what exactly I should be doing. for example U should create something and something  to do this. and that's all.(no accurate steps)

I know how to deal with mysqls and with php  but I would like to get hints of what every programmer will should do that is all.

Answer (score 0):

[DB Part]
You'll need to create a table contains 2 or 3 fields:
catID field (would be a primary key & autoincrement)
catName field (contains tha category name)
you can add a parentID (to have the catID of the parent category if there is any), imho, no real need for it as a beginner

you will need to link this table with files table taking catID as the foriegn key

[Form Part]
You can either list the categories in the uploading form, to be in a combo box, dropdown list, or even a check box, then insert it in the DB within the form,

or you can let the you user chose the category first before you show him the uploading form, then in your script you register the the catID in a session, & later when you upload the file you use that catID value

see?